# Not able to connect to SQL Server with cakephp

Tags: sql-server, cakephp

While trying to link CakePHP and SQL Server got a message :"CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database. Database connection "Sqlserver" is missing, or could not be created."
I have next settings:

- PHP 5.6.38
- CakePHP 2.5.8
- Apache 2.4.35 (Win64)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2022
- Windows 10
- SQL Server Management Studio 19
  I connect to SQL Server Management Studio 19 with Windows Authentication.
  This is my database.php in CakePHP:

```
public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlserver',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'WIN-VE77QIJJ5KO',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'test',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
```

Also I've added

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
```

to php.ini file. SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) is also running. I'm not sure if there are mistakes in database.php file or other settings.

Comment: Connecting to SQL Server 2022 requires [ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server or later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files#sql-version-compatibility). You're using such an old version of PHP and php_sqlsrv that it only supports [up to ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver#odbc-driver).

Comment: @Dale K I've changed to Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Developer, but there is still the same error. I run a function to see. which extensions are actually running and I got a result that extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll and extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll are not mentioned. Both of them are in php.ini. What might be a reason for that?

Comment: Have you enabled these in the *correct* php.ini? (There is generally one for CLI applications and a separate one for web applications.) If it's the web one you're looking at, did you restart the web server after changing it?